# jquery picture overlay roll-up

Tags: jquery

Just putting together a small script that rolls up a description over a photo.  It works fine however it's limitation is that the amount that it rolls up is a hard coded number.  So if the caption is only 1 line it works fine but if the caption is 2 lines then it (obviously) doesn't move up enough.

So what I would like to happen is have it so that on rollover the caption div rolls up so that the whole thing shows up. No matter how many lines it is.

jquery:

```
$(".hoverImage").hover(
function(){
    $(this).find(".overlay").animate({top: "108"}, 500 );
},
 function(){
    $(this).find(".overlay").animate({top: "126"}, 500 );
});
```

html:

```
    <div class="hoverImage">
    <div class="overlay">
    Headline Goes Here<br>Story text goes here<a href="">[learn more...]</a>
    </div>
    <img src="http://www.ABCDEFG.com/slice.jpg" />
    </div>
```

css:

```
<style>
.hoverImage{
width: 228px;
height: 151px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative; 
float:left;
margin-right:10px;  
}
.overlay{
width:220px;
color: #ffffff;
background: url("http://www.ABCDEFG.com/blackBg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
position: absolute;
padding-left: 5px;
top: 126px;
}
```

[you can see the example and fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vWeXU/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bottom` property, instead of `top`:

```
.overlay{
   ...
   bottom: -20px;
}
```

```
$(".hoverImage").hover(
function() {
    $(this).find(".overlay").animate({
        bottom: "0"
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".overlay").animate({
        bottom: "-20px"
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MLqWH/

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem though, because if I add more characters to the story text it shows before the roll up then. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MLqWH/1/

Comment: Your second option is something i've thought about but I was hoping to find a way to stop the roll up before it covers the entire image.

Answer (score 0):

You should put if statement like :

if $('YOUR.CLASS.NAME').val(); or if $(YOUR.CLASS.NAME).width(); IS == YOUR-PREFERRED-VALUE THEN
{YOUR ACTION} So your action could be .animate.stop() or $(this).css("width") = YOUR-PREFERED-VALUE .
I thing you should limit your THING height or width .

the other way that come to my mind is to use bottom = 0 in Jquery and use height or width to 100% .

hope it helps .